# script to automate SSIS package and stored procedures execution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012

i m trying to get a script to automate SSIS package and stored procedures execution for multiple variables on success on the preceding one, the variables are dates {201412, 201501, 201502 and so on...}
script for procedures execution is

```
`exec [dbo].[ALIM_AGE_RANGE]
 exec [dbo].[ALIM_CATEGORY_EMPLOYEE]
 exec [dbo].[ALIM_CURRENCY]  201503
 exec [dbo].[ALIM_EMPLOYEE]
 exec [dbo].[ALIM_HR_DISCIPLINE]
 exec [dbo].[ALIM_ORGANIZATION]
 exec [dbo].[ALIM_RECRUITMENT_REASON]
 exec [dbo].[ALIM_ROLE]
 exec [dbo].[ALIM_STATUS_EMPLOYEE]
 exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_HR_FACT] 201503`
```

thank you

---

Answer on how to automate stored procedures to run for multiple values of one variable, one after an other: (still looking how to do so for an ssis package)

```
USE [HR_DTM]
GO

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tab') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
truncate table #tab
end

go
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_AGE_RANGE]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_CALENDAR]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_CATEGORY_EMPLOYEE]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_COUNTRY]

        EXEC [dbo].[P_ALIM_EMPLOYEE]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_GLOBAL_GRADE]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_HR_DISCIPLINE]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_ORGANIZATION]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_RECRUITMENT_REASON]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_ROLE]
        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_STATUS_EMPLOYEE]



IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tab') IS NULL)
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #tab(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), param_value int);
END


INSERT INTO #tab(param_value)
VALUES (201412), (201501),  (201502), (201503), (201504),(201505), (201506),(201507), (201508), (201509); -- ...

DECLARE @counter INT = 1,
    @param bigint;
    --@param2 datetime = convert (datetime, @param) @param;

WHILE @counter <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #tab)
BEGIN
 SELECT @param = param_value
FROM #tab
WHERE id = @counter;


        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_CURRENCY] @param


        exec [dbo].[P_ALIM_HR_FACT] @param

SET @counter += 1;
END
```

Comment: Is your request: How can I run a use a list of values as the source for a set of stored procedures in SSIS?

Comment: No, actually a have an SSIS and a set of stored procedures that needs to be executed giving a parameter (a date period), first period: 201412, on success i execute the second period: 201501 and so on

Comment: So the Package has a Variable that you need to assign a value into. After the package runs, you then need to pass the same variable to the stored procedures?

Comment: Why didn't your foreach attempt work?    Did you get an error?

Comment: @billinkc when the first execution with the first variable "201412" is done succesffuly, i need to reexecute the same set of stored procs with the next variable "201501" and so on

Comment: @TabAlleman my foreach didnt work cause i didnt do it correctly, didn t know how to index my values (201401, 201501, 201502) to give em the (1,2,3) abstract values so i can call em with i=i+1 or something like that

Comment: You don't need abstract values.   How did you try to do it?   Just use ForEach to iterate over an ordered dataset of values.   In SSIS the advance to the next value happens automatically, you don't have to specify it.